# Apache Security Issue with VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, security, centos6

I have setup Apache 2.2+php 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.6 and are running virtual hosts with their document roots setup like /var/www/domainFoldername and their virtual hosts configuration in httpd.conf like:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/ExampleFolder/web
ServerAlias example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com$
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
ErrorLog /var/www/ExampleFolder/log/error.log
TransferLog /var/www/ExampleFolder/log/access.log
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
php_admin_flag safe_mode Off
ErrorDocument 400 /error/invalidSyntax.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error/authorizationRequired.html
ErrorDocument 402 /error/forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error/forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error/methodNotAllowed.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error/internalServerError.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error/overloaded.html
</VirtualHost>
```

I am also using ACLs and have given apache write access to /var/www for file uploading permission issues through script. Problem I am facing is of security. I can run a script from the domain `example.com` and have it access files that exist in another domain's directory. I would think that scripts belonging to the domain `example.com` should only be able to access files within `/var/www/example/`, not within `/var/www/someotherdomain`. So, currently its very insecure and I want to secure these things.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute php script in DomainName1 from DomainName2"? How exactly is the script called/executed?

Comment: Also, you have two `RewriteCond` but no RewriteRule, so there is no rewrite happening at all here.

Comment: Well, actually I have blog rewrite rules, but did not paste them as I thought they would be irrelevant from actual question.

Comment: They probably are, so that was a good call. But I still don't understand exactly how the scripts are being executed.

Comment: @JennyD Like, if I would execute **bold**exec("tar -zcvf test.tar.zip /var/www/DomainName1Folder");**bold** from DomainName2 , it would create that asked tar.zip file in DomainName1.

Comment: I've made an edit, could you check that I understood you right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Apache run scripts as different Linux user accounts based on which VirtualHost is being accessed.  There are multiple solutions to this, for example suPHP, suEXEC, and others.  Be sure you're not trying to run PHP as an Apache module (i.e. mod_php) because then it will run as the Apache user which has permission to any user's directory.  Then you just need to make sure that each VirtualHost's user account can't access the other VirtualHosts' directories and only Apache's user account is able to.

To isolate things further if you wanted each Apache VirtualHost to run as its own user and not just scripts, you can use something like MPM ITK (though at the expense of speed and also trading off for some other security concerns as mentioned on the "Quirks and Warnings" section of its homepage).

You may want to check out CloudLinux (I think you can do an in-place upgrade of CentOS to it), and its CageFS and mod_lsapi offerings as the combination of those two offer good security and performance.

Another note is make sure you implement symlink attack protection to prevent one site from reading the files from the other via an Apache trick (CloudLinux has a kernel modification which provides protection against this, and there are other solutions as well such as disallowing `FollowSymLinks` altogether - see https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Symlink+Race+Condition+Protection if you want to read more about various approaches).

Comment: Thanks .... yes, these definitely are solutions. But kind of application I have, I can't use cPanel or cloudlinux. It must be a manually compiled apache. Can I have Symlink Race Condition Protection without cPanel?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to use symlinks, just turn off symlink support by setting `Options -FollowSymLinks` in your master httpd.conf.  Make sure you have the `AllowOverride` directive configured so that individual sites can't override that setting by setting `Options +FollowSymLinks` in an .htaccess file.